# Obtaining a .virgin Domain Name

Tags: dns, tld

So I've recently found out that there is a ".virgin" gTLD.
Is it even possible to obtain a domain ending in .virgin and if yes,
how would one go about doing so?

Thank you for your replies, and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.VIRGIN` TLD as been awarded to "Virgin Enterprises Limited", see https://gtldresult.icann.org/applicationstatus/applicationdetails/378

The TLD was delegated (inserted in root zone and starting to resolve) around October 2015 as you can see on https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/virgin.html

You can find the registry contract online here: https://www.icann.org/resources/agreement/virgin-2014-09-25-en

It is a "brand TLD" also called a "Specification 13" TLD inside ICANN circles.

This means the TLD is owned by an entity that is basically planning to use it for its only internal needs, and it will not be open to outside registrations.

The full detail of "Specification 13" is here:
https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/agb/base-agreement-contracting/specification-13-applications

Among other things it says:

> Only Registry Operator, its Affiliates or Trademark Licensees are registrants of domain names in the TLD and control the DNS records associated with domain names at any level in the TLD;

(a gTLD application coverned by this Specification 13 entails various simplified procedures and contracts, as long as it is indeed really a "brand" TLD)

Which means it is a closed TLD, you will not be able to register anything in it, so no domain names jokes with `.virgin`!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a branded gTLD - for Virgin Group Ltd.

I found the following:

> Applicant Virgin Enterprises Limited has applied for the .virgin domain. As this is a branded domain, this will initially not be available for public registrations. Review the application for more information.